# Mapping error while persisting JPA object

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm getting stuck with this error in a week. **Could anyone explain why I'm getting this error and how to solve it?**

I have an Entiry class **Version** and I want to return the Id after persist an Version entity object. But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-71] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A NullPointerException was thrown while setting the value of the instance variable [id] to the value [38].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[id-->Version.ID]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(varick.rap.demo.entities.VersionPK --> [DatabaseTable(Version)])
```

This is my full code:

```
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_NAME);
    entity = factory.createEntityManager();
    entity.getTransaction().begin();

    Version version = new Version();
    version.setVersion(getNext(this.version));
    version.setProjectID(projectID);
    entity.persist(version);
    entity.flush();
    System.out.println("Version Id: " + version.getId());
    entity.getTransaction().commit();
```

Version entity class(this class is using an @EmbeddedId):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Version")
public class Version implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId 
    private VersionPK id;

    @Column(name="Version")
    private String version;

    @Column(name="ProjectID")
    private int projectID;

    public Version() {
    }

    public VersionPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    //get and set methods here
```

VersionPK class:

```
@Embeddable
public class VersionPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    public VersionPK() {
    }
    //get and set method here
```

Comment: Why are you using a VersionPK with a single attribute that is autogenerated?  The NPE seems to be due to the VersionPK instance being null, so its id value cannot be set.  Try initializing the VersionPK, though you are better off not using an Embedded ID and instead mapping the int id directly in your entity.

Comment: Thank you for quick comment. I'm looking for a way that not make change entity class. But if no way else I think I have no choice.

Comment: try initializing the versionPK instance in the entity with an empty instance.

Answer (score 0):

the primary key is not set. maybe you should do like this :

```
VersionPK pk = new VersionPK();
pk.setId("****");

Version version = new Version();
version.setId(pk);
version.setVersion(getNext(this.version));
version.setProjectID(projectID);
entity.persist(version);
entity.flush();
System.out.println("Version Id: " + version.getId());
entity.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: In the entity object the id is null. But if I persist without flush. My database(MySQL) will auto generate an ID itself. I checked it on DB.